How to assign variables to the SQL query logic fetched from a table in snowflake using JS
I have a table which has SQL validation logic which I need to fetch in a loop and execute each rule id.
VALIDATION_RULES table has the following columns:
RuleID, SQL_Logic

Orchestration stored procedure: it will loop through each of the ruleid, pull the SQL logic and executes that SQL logic.
SQL Logic: Check if column A exists in table (this is dynamic table) then execute validation SQL logic and insert it to a static table. If the column A does not exists then insert nothing  .
Example of SQL_Logic:
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME=''A'' AND TABLE_NAME = ${dynamic_table})) THEN
let sql_res TEXT:=''INSERT INTO STATIC_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3) SELECT ${P1},${P2},COL5 FROM ${dynamic_table} WHERE LEN(IFNULL(A,'''')) = 0;'';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_res;

ELSE 
let sq_res TEXT:= ''INSERT INTO STATIC_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3) SELECT ${P1},${P2},COL5 FROM ${dynamic_table} WHERE 1 = 0;'';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_res;
END IF;
END;
$$;

I am calling this SQL logic sitting in a VALIDATION_RULES table using a JS stored procedure which looks something like this
function loop_through_rules(rule_id,dynamic_table,P1,P2){
        get_validation_rules = `select * from VALIDATION_RULES where RULE_ID =${rule_id}`;
        snowflake.execute({sqlText: get_validation_rules});
        rs.next();
        for (i = 1; i <= rs.getRowCount(); i++) {
            sql_logic = rs.getColumnValue(2) -- COLUMN WHERE the validation logic exists in validation rules table
            
            snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_logic});
            rs.next();
        }
        return sql_logic;    
    }

/* function call * //
res = loop_through_rules(rule_id,dynamic_table,P1,P2); 
return res;

How can I inject the variables to into validation SQL logic and execute it?
